# How can I get os.Errno from os.Error? Other ways to use os.Timeout?

Tags: sockets, error-handling, go

The [net.Conn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) interface provides the SetTimeout methods and I am supposed to check the returned error with [os.Timeout](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Errno.Timeout). However I see no way of calling os.Timeout on the returned os.Error.

(The os.Error I've got is `read unix @: Resource temporarily unavailable` which seem to consists of two parts: description of the function which timed out and the `strerror` description of the `EAGAIN`. I've tried `err == os.EAGAIN` and it doesn't work, probably because of the extra information in os.Error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a [type assertion](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions). Let's say **kon** is type net.Conn and you read into buffer **buf**. Then:

```
if numread, err := kon.Read(buf); err != nil {
    if val, ok := err.(os.Errno); ok {
        if val.Timeout() {
            println("Connection to:", kon.RemoteAddr().String(), "timed out.")
        }
    }
}
```

That's of course only a gist of the idea. In practice you probably want to do something more elegant (aka more RL complexleete) and consider more cases at once with [Type switches](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_switches).

Comment: Thanks. The technique is also described in http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors

Comment: @ArtemGr Yeah, it's pretty basic thing, but most "newlygot" think in the categories of concrete (say int or string in this case, lower down one might have had to resort to C.errno) not abstract/dynamic types enabled by interface{} duck typing.

Answer (score 1):

The "An I/O Package" section of the [Go tutorial](http://golang.org/doc/go_tutorial.html) has this snippet:

```
func OpenFile(name string, mode int, perm uint32) (file *File, err os.Error) {
  r, e := syscall.Open(name, mode, perm)
  if e != 0 {
    err = os.Errno(e)
  }
  return newFile(r, name), err
}
```

`syscall.Open()` has this signature:

```
func Open(path string, mode int, perm uint32) (fd int, errno int)
```

So I think it's safe to assume `os.Error` is still just that integer error code, just with the added fluff and your approach to check it is correct.

To investigate why `err == os.EAGAIN` did not work for you, I'd print the error as a value of type `int` and then grepped your platform's `errno.h` file for the value printed.

Comment: No, it is not an int. `fmt.Printf ("type: %T; int value: %i\n", err, err)` prints `type: *net.OpError; int value: %!i(string=read unix @: resource temporarily unavailable)`.